# Racket C structs don't get reclaimed automatically

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, racket, ffi

I have a binding to a C library.

```
(define-cstruct _rect
  ([x _int]
   [y _int]
   [w _int]
   [h _int]))
```

And I want to use this object in programs.

```
(require ffi/unsafe
         (rename-in "sdl-structs.rkt"
                    [make-rect _make-rect]))

(module rect racket
  (provide (all-defined-out)))

(define (make-rect x y w h)
  (define new-rect (_make-rect x y w h))
  new-rect)

(define (left rect)
  (rect-x rect))

(define (top rect)
  (rect-y rect))

...

(define (bottom-left rect)
  (values (left rect) (bottom rect)))

(define (bottom-right rect)
  (values (right rect) (bottom rect)))
```

But there's currently a memory leak. It takes a while to crash, but it still crashes.

```
(define (eat-memory)
  (define memory (current-memory-use))
  (define (eat-loop)
    (begin
      (make-rect 0 0 1 1)
      (displayln memory)
      (set! memory (current-memory-use))
      (eat-loop)))
  (eat-loop))
```

I want to have the memory automatically reclaimed, how would I go about doing it? I've looked at the [documentation on finalization of memory](http://download.racket-lang.org/docs/5.0.2/html/foreign/Allocation_and_Finalization.html), but I don't see how that's supposed to be helpful. Wouldn't I need to call each of the functions manually anyway?

Comment: Your `eat-memory` function looks a little suspicious.  Look at how `eat-memory` calls `eat-loop`, which calls into... `eat-memory` again!  I think you mean for `eat-loop` to call itself as `eat-loop`.  Normally, this should still be ok, since the call is a tail call, but if your language settings are trying to produce good stack traces, it may be possible that you're not getting good tail-optimizing behavior out of this particular mutually-recursive loop.

Comment: @dyoo Are you saying that the code shouldn't normally leak memory?

Comment: I don't believe it should be leaking.  I see no internal pointers in your `_rect` definition, so that shouldn't be causing the GC to get confused.  I'd recommend checking with the racket-users mailing list if you can.  Unfortunately, I don't have time to help debug this at the moment.  :(

Comment: I changed the eat-memory function to recurse directly, the OOM error still persists.

Comment: Yeah, check with the official racket-users mailing list about this one then.  Looks suspicious.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the core of your code, without the extra noise:

```
#lang racket
(require ffi/unsafe)
(define-cstruct _rect ([x _int] [y _int] [w _int] [h _int]))
(let loop ([n 0])
  (make-rect 0 0 1 1)
  ;; (list 0 0 1 1)
  (displayln (current-memory-use))
  (loop (add1 n)))
```

If you run it, you'll see what looks like a leak.  Now flip the comments to use `list` and you'll see a similar leak.  The thing is that you're printing the memory use after each an every allocation, and it takes a good while to reach a point where the GC starts working.  If you change it to do the printout less frequently, you'll see a stable memory.  Here's what I run to see this:

```
#lang racket
(require ffi/unsafe)
(define-cstruct _rect ([x _int] [y _int] [w _int] [h _int]))
(let loop ([n 0])
  (make-rect 0 0 1 1)
  (when (zero? (modulo n 100000)) (displayln (current-memory-use)))
  (loop (add1 n)))
```

That being said, it is easy to get memory leaks when you're using the unsafe FFI, and you're using a library that might a problem itself, and after all of that, it might be that there's some other bug...